# Minimum Number of Steps to Make Two Strings Anagram and 2 strings are of same length and have only lower case letters

Tags: string

> i am using 2 int arrays to count each strings number of each character

```
class Solution {
public int minSteps(String s, String t) {
    int c=0,i;
    int[] arr1=new int[26];
      int[] arr2=new int[26];
    
    for(i=0;i<t.length();i++)
    {
        arr1[s.charAt(i)-97]++;
          arr2[t.charAt(i)-97]++;
    }
    System.out.println(arr1[1]);
            System.out.println(arr2[1]);
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]>arr2[i])
        c+=(arr1[i]-arr2[i]);
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

> this works fine java and passes all test cases but when i use this in c

`enter code here`int minSteps(char * s, char * t){

int arr1[26]={};

int arr2[26]={};

int i,c=0;

char x;

```
for( i=0;i<sizeof(s);i++)
{
   
arr1[(s[i]-97)]++;

arr2[(t[i]-97)]++;

}
 for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{

if(arr1[i]!=arr2[i])c++;

}

return c;
```

}

> here it shows following error
> Line 10: Char 9: runtime error: index -97 out of bounds for type 'int [26]' [solution.c]

Help!!!

Comment: Please properly [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Is `s` an empty string in your C implementation? If so accessing the first char of an empty string could be the null terminator, which would give you an array index of `-97`.

Comment: No s isnt an empty string